# OSM is not displayed with projection EPSG:3067 in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am quite new to Openlayers and struggling with projections. I try to create map with projection EPSG:3067 but my code is not showing anything. My code tries to define projection with library proj4js and use projection in openlayers map. Code does not give any error and after long search in openlayers documents, I am still unable to find error. Where the error might be?:

```
<script>
//Defining projection with proj4
proj4.defs('EPSG:3067','+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

//Creating projection to Openlayer
var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3067');

//Defining extent and settingit to projection
var extent = [50199.4814, 6582464.0358, 761274.6247, 7799839.8902];
projection.setExtent(extent);

//Creating map
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    //Creating view for map
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
        extent: extent,
        zoom: 4
    })
});

</script>
```

Comment: There's no center defined.  If you add (for example) `center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),` to the view definition it should work.

Comment: Yes, it is working with this advice. I added first `center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent), `. I also tried later to input coordinates in EPSG:3067 and center was working as expected.